# jna installation for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, jna

I started to install `datastax` by referring [this link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html?). It requires `jna` for performance improvement.

I am using `ubuntu:12.04` system. I installed using

```
 sudo apt-get install libjna-java
```

I din't get any error. But there is a list of steps specified for `ubuntu:10.04`. So it confused me whether i installed jna proper version which supports cassandra.

I googled it for `jna verification` but i end up with only one little useful [link](https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/11/11/enabling-jna-in-cassandra/). It says about logs. So

1. How do i verify ubuntu:12.04 is compatible with the jna version i installed
2. And where ll be the log file to check for logs
3. And Do i must write a c or c++ program to check jna or is there any commands such as verifying `java i.e java -version`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `java -jar jna.jar` will give you information about the JNA version.

Comment: I din't install from jar. I just used apt command

Comment: The `apt` command will have installed jna.jar somewhere on your system.  Alternatively, ask `apt` what version it installed: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude